# javascript string split for string containing backslashes

Tags: javascript

I have a string like `C:\Users\shail.jet\Desktop\cca-lan_test_cases_path.txt`.

I want to get only file name that is in this case is `cca-lan_test_cases_path.txt`.I have tried it with javascript split function but it did'nt work. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `str.substring(str.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1)` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

```
 "C:\\Users\\shail.jet\\Desktop\\cca-lan_test_cases_path.txt".split("\\").pop();
```

Make sure you add escape backslashes in the file path string otherwise javascript will ignore it.

That will split by backslash and then use pop to get the last element in the array which will be the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')
```

This will handle both \ OR / in paths

```
var filename = fullPath.replace(/^.*(\\|\/|\:)/, '');
```

should also protect from empty string